# View becomes smaller on every call to onMeasure() and onSizeChanged()

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a custom view with just a circle inside it.
I have a problem with its dimensions.

I overrode both `onSizeChanged()` and `onMeasure()`, but I'm afraid I'm missing something with `onMeasure()`. This view being substantially just a circle, I overrode `getSuggestedMinimumHeight()` and `getSuggestedMinimumWidth()` in order to make both of them return the radius of the circle. Now everything seemed to work fine until I decided to update some other components of the activity.

When I update the text of a `TextView` (or a `Button`) in the activity where my view is situated, my view becomes smaller (on every update) calling both `onMeasure()` and `onSizeChanged()`.

Here is my `onMeasure()` method. My question is: why doesn't it behaves always the same?

```
@Override
protected int getSuggestedMinimumHeight() {
    return (int) (mCircleRadius + mCircleStrokeWidth/2);
}

@Override
protected int getSuggestedMinimumWidth() {
    return (int) (mCircleRadius + mCircleStrokeWidth/2);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
Log.d("SIZES", "called onMeasure()");

    int minw = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getSuggestedMinimumWidth();

    int minh = getSuggestedMinimumHeight() + getPaddingBottom() + getPaddingTop();

    setMeasuredDimension(minw, minh);
}
```

Here's the XML for the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.nhasu"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.nhasu.ProgressCircleTimer
        android:id="@+id/progcircle_smallBreaks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        custom:circle_radius="300dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        android:onClick="onStartClicked"
        android:text="@string/btn_start"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that I edit the text of the `Button` with a simple `Button.setText()`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reduces itself'?

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston That it changes size and becomes smaller.

Comment: Your implementation of onMeasure tells Android to never make it larger than the minimum size (radius + half the border width + some padding) . Do you need it to be larger than that?

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston Ah, that's what `onMeasure` it's for. Actually what I would like is that Android makes that view at most that large: it can be smaller but it can't be bigger. Anyway, what could I do in order to make the view *exactly* the size I want, not bigger nor smaller?

Comment: I'll prepare an answer for you. For now, note that the parent-View has a say in the size of its children (e.g. your custom view), but you can 'coach' the parent into the correct behavior. :)

Comment: Ok. I want to use xml layout as much as possible, so I would like to set `android:layout_width/height` to `wrap_content` for my custom view, and then specify a custom attribute `custom:radius` that specifies the maximum radius for the circle.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `onSizeChanged` to determine the size of your custom view. When the `onSizeChanged` is called, your custom view has been measured and laid-out.

Just implement the `onMeasure` appropriately:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Log.d("SIZES", "called onMeasure()");

    int minw = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
    int minh = getSuggestedMinimumHeight() + getPaddingBottom() + getPaddingTop();

    setMeasuredDimension(
            resolveSize(minw, widthMeasureSpec),
            resolveSize(minh, heightMeasureSpec));
}

public static int resolveSize(int childSize, int measureSpec) {
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
    switch (specMode) {
    case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        // Just return the child's size.
        return childSize;

    case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        // Return the smallest of childSize and specSize
        return (specSize < childSize)? specSize : childSize;

    case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
        // Should honor parent-View's request for the given size.
        // If not desired, don't set the child's layout_width/layout_height to a fixed
        // value (nor fill_parent in certain cases).
        return specSize;
    }

    return childSize;
}
```

I added the implementation of `resolveSize` to this answer so you can see what happens, but it is already implemented for you in `View.resolveSize`.

Comment: That behaves exactly like before. I have to custom views in my activity, and a `Button`. Every time the `Button` changes its text, the views become smaller. I really can't find out what's happening.

Comment: Put a break-point in the onMeasure and see what happens. Also, could you post the XML layout in which your custom view is defined. It may be telling on what's going on. I'm suspicious that the 'case Measure.EXACTLY' is called by the code which may mess with your desired layout.

Comment: Mmmmmmmm, your layout looks ok. You should debug the onMeasure of your custom view (put a breakpoint there) and see what happens after you change the button's text.

Comment: Ok, here's another thing I just noticed: first, only width changes while height remains the same. Second, changing `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` seems to solve this issue.